# How do I run livereload server on localhost after running Ionic serve command?

Tags: ionic-framework

I recently started learning Ionic Framework. You can use `Ionic serve` command inside the project to run a livereload server. Once in a while it asked whether server should run on `localhost` or `system ip`. I chose second option. Now It doesn't ask anything and directly runs on system's `ip`.

How do reset this automatic behaviour?

I tried looking into [`serve.js`](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/blob/master/lib/ionic/serve.js)   file in `ionic-cli` project but no luck.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It's not necessary to edit the code. You can switch between addresses with the command `ionic address`. You'll then get options like this:

```
Please select which address to use by entering its number from the list below:
 1) 10.0.1.7 (en1)
 2) localhost
```

Comment: I was looking for it all over. Thanks! Why isn't it mentioned anywhere in docs? where did you find it?

Answer (score 5):

like  @user3110357 points out you can just type `ionic address` command and you get the option to select your IP address again.

OR

you can explicitly select your address and port when you run `ionic serve`

by using the `--address` and `--port` options. Like this:

`ionic serve --address IP_address --port port`

example : `ionic serve --address 192.168.1.129  --port 8101`

**Things to note**

- If you do not provide a port option with `--address` the       default port(8100) is used instead.
- Specifying address and port will only change the settings for that session. if you need to override saved settings, you should probably use the `ionic address` command instead.

Comment: I modified the answer @kushdilip

Answer (score 2):

Found a workaround. I am using this method on ubuntu so paths may be different for other os.

Go to `/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/ionic`

Open `serve.js` with root user.

Find function called `IonicTask.prototype.getAddress`

Inside this function the value of variable `isAddressCmd` is false. Set it to true

```
self.isAddressCmd = false;
```

save the file. Now run `Ionic serve` for your project. This time it will ask for `localhost` vs `ip` again.

After this remove the newly added code from `serve.js` otherwise `ionic serve` won't work.